# getstatuscode is not working with phantomJS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, bdd, behat, mink

I am testing a web app with loads and loads of web pages and I would like to verify that none of the URLs are broken on every commit. Here is a code snippet.

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$page_URLs = $page->findAll('css', 'header nav ul a');     
assertEquals(16, count($page_URLs)); 

foreach($page_URLs as $pageUrl){
    try{
        $pageUrl->click();
        $statusCode = $this->getSession()->getStatusCode();
        echo $pageUrl->getText();
        assertEquals(200, $statusCode, "The webpage is not available");      
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
        $this->getSession()->back();
}
```

I was using the Behat, MINK with Goutte driver (as a headless browser) for CI integration (and getStatusCode() was working fine). But most of the functionality on the web app is java script driven therefore I have to move on to PhantomJS which support javascript. But I didn't realise that getStatusCode() doesn't work with PhantomJS.

Has anyone got any idea if I can replace this with something and get the similar result.

Comment: Care to comment why on earth someone would downvote this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS support in Behat is realised via the WebDriver protocol (selenium). WebDriver [doesn't support inspecting status codes on purpose](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141), as it falls out of scope of emulating user actions.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for confirming that Jakub. On a different note if I loop through different parts of the app, how can I make sure the pages are not broken.